# How to remove: Notice: You’re using the auto-generated password for your account. Would you like to change it?

Tags: dashboard

I'm using social sign up buttons on my Wordpress site to register/sign in using Google, FB, TW...

When they are logged in, this notice appear on the top of the Wordpress  dashboard:

> Notice: You’re using the auto-generated password for your account. Would you like to change it?

Is it possible to remove this notice?

It's misleading users.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @robert0's answer, you can unhook the nag from happening:

```php
remove_action( 'profile_update', 'default_password_nag_edit_user', 10 );
```

Just put that in your theme's `functions.php` and that should take care of it.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution.

This will remove all the notices for your registered WordPress users, except admins:

```
function hide_update_noticee_to_all_but_admin_users()
{
    if (!is_super_admin()) {
        remove_all_actions( 'admin_notices' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_noticee_to_all_but_admin_users', 1 );
```

Add the above code to functions.php

Comment: This does not happen on `admin_notices`, it appears on a user's profile page via the `profile_update` action.

Comment: You really shouldn't be removing _all_ actions. This is drastic overkill and will result in other important notices being removed.